# Modify api Results - Name of object - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I had to change APIS and I am unable to modify the client code. I have include the node code that should manipulate the data. Error `[ReferenceError: obj is not defined]` I have the following code which includes api response, node code, and snippet of my angular expression.

```
// api response 
{
  "active_id": null,
  "enabled": true,
  "last_modified": 14700220477943,
  "latitude": 37.235205,
  "longitude": -121.874178,
  "expiration": null,           // need to change this to 'countdown'
  "location_id": "0d16"
},

//node stuff 


app.get('/raw_data', (req, res) => {
  const { swLat, swLng, neLat, neLng } = req.query;
  axios.get(`http://newURl?bounds=${swLat},${swLng},${neLat},${neLng}`)
    .then((apiRes) => {
      const { data } = apiRes;

      let newData;

      // Manipulate the `data`, then set it to newData

      data.obj.expiration = newData.obj.countdown;

      res.send(data);

      // Return the manipulated data
       res.send(newData);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});

//angular code uses 
 {{object.counter}} // not "expiration"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a `countdown` property to the object, assuming it's ok to keep the unused `expiration` property:

```
var obj = {
  //...
  "expiration": null,
  //...
};
obj.countdown = obj.expiration;

//...

{{obj.countdown}}
```

Otherwise you could just create a new object with the fields you need:

```
var obj1 = ...;
var obj2 = {
  countdown: obj.expiration,
  //...
};
```

Comment: hi, in node, i am getting an error at the dot after obj. any ideas

Comment: What specifically is the error? Note that my code was an example; replace the variable names with those of your own variables.

Comment: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'obj' of undefined] // I am using my own variables

Comment: Hmmm... what is the offending statement?

Comment: If you want to manipulate `data` directly, replace `data.obj` with just `data`. `data` itself is an object.

Comment: Oh wait – if `data === undefined` then you have a different problem

Comment: yeah. idk what it is, do you see it?

Comment: Try console.log'ing `apiRes` and `data`

Comment: i did, it returns like it should but keeps throwing that error

Comment: What did `console.log` say the values of `apiRes` and `data` were?